# Pdf with multiple columns under header by using TGDIPages from SynPdf

Tags: delphi, pdf, synpdf

I would like to generate a PDF file by using `TGDIPages` method and having multiple columns under header with text and a logo.

Example:

```
Quotation               [Some logo here]            Company Name                             
No. xx / 03.05.2018                                 Stree, No, Region, Country
```

With `TPdfDocumentGDI` it's easy to arrange the text on canvas, but with this method I had difficulties with calculation of pagination.

Please some suggestions.

https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4430

Comment: @whosrdaddy `TGDIPages` is a report engine. ;)

Comment: ok never mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `OnStartPageHeader` and `OnEndPageHeader` events to add your own content to the header.

Those events are triggered before and after the `TGDIPages.DoHeaderFooterInternal` method, which draws the default header information.

Comment: Do you have any example... maybe under `Samples` folder?

Comment: After discovering better the framework, it's really easy to create pdf reports. Well done!